# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 on an input file program

Tags: java, swing, indexoutofboundsexception

I am receiving a message: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 
when trying to run the below code. This program is taking the input from a text file, conducting some salary numbers, and outputting their gross pay.

This is the contents of the text file:
http://m.uploadedit.com/b034/139892732049.txt

```
 package payroll;

 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

 public class PayRoll
 {
    private String empName;
    private int hours;
    private int hourlyPayRate;

    public PayRoll(String name, int hh, int rr)
    {
        empName = name;
        hours = hh;
        hourlyPayRate = rr;      
    }  

    public String getName()
    {
        return empName;
    }

    public double getPay()
    {
        if(hours <= 40)
            return hours * hourlyPayRate;
        else
            return (40 * hourlyPayRate) + (hours - 40) * 1.5 * hourlyPayRate;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {  
        Scanner inFile = null;

        try
        {
        inFile = new Scanner(new File("payroll.txt"));
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String name;
        String first;
        String last;
        int hh;
        int rr;
        String result = "Details of employees:\n";

        while(inFile.hasNextLine())
        {
            String line = inFile.nextLine();

            String tokens[] = line.split(" ");

           first = tokens[0];
           last = tokens[1];
            hh = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
            rr = Integer.parseInt(tokens[3]);

            name = first + " " + last;

            PayRoll payroll = new PayRoll(name, hh, rr);

            result += "Name: " + payroll.getName() + ", GrossPay: $" + payroll.getPay() + "\n";
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, result);

        inFile.close();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Which line of code and of your data file  cause the exception?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you have blank lines in your file which results in a zero length token array

Verify the length of your token array after each read.

```
  if (token == null || token.length != 4) continue;
```

or of course as Duncan suggests simply skip empty lines or both (better option).

```
  if (line == null || line.trim().length() < 1) continue;
```

Both of these checks should be done, and maybe reported on separately.

Comment: Or strip blank lines before the `split`. That would help differentiate between lines that are malformed and lines that are merely empty.

Comment: @IwishIcouldthinkofagood how would I be able to to skip empty lines at this point? I edited the text file and removed any empty lines I can find. Not sure if it would be helpful or not but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You are not checking how many tokens you have after doing `String tokens[] = line.split(" ");`

If the split results in less that 2 tokens, you will get the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

You should probably add a check like:

```
if(tokens.length < 2) {
   continue;
}
```

Comment: I agree the check should be made, but the input string does have four space-separated strings.

Comment: How would you suggest I go about changing that? I'm pretty much fried at this point so any incite would be great.

Comment: @Pshemo Good point. This answer would address that issue, although I gave the upvote to the other answer too because he seemed to point out the underlying problem first.

Comment: @geoand I attempted to added your check within the while loop and it did not solve the issue. Am I placing it wrong?

Comment: Place it right after `String tokens[] = line.split(" ");` and it should be ok

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see your data file contains empty lines. I believe that the first empty line causes this problem because `split()` returns empty (zero length) array.

Answer (score 0):

The last line in the `payroll.txt` file is an empty line, so when it is split, it will will generate an array having size one. Then this (`last = tokens[1];`) line of code will obviously make an error.

Rewrite your code as follows, I have added to trim the line before splitting, and added a `continue` in the while loop.

```
package payroll;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class PayRoll {
    private String empName;
    private int hours;
    private int hourlyPayRate;

    public PayRoll(String name, int hh, int rr) {
        empName = name;
        hours = hh;
        hourlyPayRate = rr;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return empName;
    }

    public double getPay() {
        if (hours <= 40)
            return hours * hourlyPayRate;
        else
            return (40 * hourlyPayRate) + (hours - 40) * 1.5 * hourlyPayRate;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner inFile = null;

        try {
            inFile = new Scanner(new File(
                    "C:\\Users\\Visruth\\Desktop\\payroll.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String name = null;
        String first = null;
        String last = null;
        int hh;
        int rr;
        String result = "Details of employees:\n";

        while (inFile.hasNextLine()) {

            String line = inFile.nextLine().trim();
            System.out.println(line);
            String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
            if (tokens.length != 4) {
                continue;
            }

            first = tokens[0];
            last = tokens[1];
            hh = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
            rr = Integer.parseInt(tokens[3]);

            name = first + " " + last;

            PayRoll payroll = new PayRoll(name, hh, rr);

            result += "Name: " + payroll.getName() + ", GrossPay: $"
                    + payroll.getPay() + "\n";
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, result);

        inFile.close();
    }
}
```